# Socket works too slow :: java/libgdx

Tags: java, sockets, libgdx

I am using java/libgdx and I have encountered problem with sockets. It works slow. My little game  presents character, which move left and right. After sending by tcp/localhost, it moves slower. I add two pieces of codes from Client and Server class. Please help me. I stucked. Thanks in advance. If it is necessary I will put whole code.

//CLIENT

```
    public class ClientThread extends Thread{

    public void run(){

        hints = new SocketHints();
        hints.connectTimeout = 11000;

        while(trwanie)
        {
            socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, "localhost", 8784, hints );
                if(!socket.isConnected() )
                    System.out.println("NIE JEST");
                //System.out.println("socket null?");
            if(socket!=null)
            {
                try {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(new String("CZESC server").getBytes()); // wiadomosc wysylana
                    //byte[] read = new byte[1024];
                    socket.getInputStream().read(read); //odebrana od servera
                    readString = new String(read).trim();
                    XY = readString;
                    StringToFloat();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();socket.dispose();
                }
            }
            //socket.dispose(); 
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE))
            {
                 WylaczPentle();
                 System.out.println("Wychodzimy z pentli");
                 Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        }
        socket.dispose();       
    }
}
```

//Server

```
    public class ServerThread extends Thread{

    public void run()
    {
        hints = new ServerSocketHints();
        hints.acceptTimeout = 12000;
        socketHints = new SocketHints();
        while(trwanie)
        {
            server = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Protocol.TCP, "localhost", 8784, hints);   
            socket  = server.accept(socketHints);
            if(socket != null)
            {
                //byte[] read = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    socket.getInputStream().read(read);
                    socket.getOutputStream().write( (WspolzednaX+"/"+WspolzednaY).getBytes());                                                                          //---

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    server.dispose();
                }
            }
            server.dispose();
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE))
            {
                 WylaczPentle();
                 System.out.println("Wychodzimy z pentli");
                 Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        }
        server.dispose();   
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you want wo write Strings you should better use a DataOutputStream and [writeUTF()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)). And don't forget to flush the written data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason that your code is slow is that your client seems to be repeatedly opening / using / closing a socket to the same server.  Considering that opening and closing takes a significant amount of time (to perform the network packet exchanges), you would do better opening the Socket once, and keeping it open while the client and server exchange multiple "messages".

There are other problems with your code.  For example, the `read(bytes[])` method returns an `int` that says how many bytes were *actually* read.  Your client and server side code is ignoring that, and assuming that all `read.length` bytes in the buffer contain valid data.

Comment: Thanks for smart tip, I corrected: 
socket.getInputStream().read(read, 0, read.length);

Concerning first paragraph, I am aware of this fact. But every time I try to dump some parts from whille(), exceptons or some errors all hell  breaks looses. How can I change my code in while(trwanie) ? [trwanie = eng. lasting] ?, should I past here errors from console? Please help. I think it's main problem of my game.Thanks a lot for all help

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED :) 
The problem was with meeting client and server. I added thread 0,5s before while(), now it works well : ))

Thanks everybody.

Comment: You do not need to add sleeps to networking code. There are already blocks built in. Sleeping in networking code is just literally a waste of time. All it does is to mask other bugs such as ignoring the length returned by `read()`, and those bugs will return.